# How to set tint/highlight color in table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my table view,I have a cell like this:[image]

When it was selected and that orange rectangle changed to gray.But I want it to keep orange.I have set tint color but it seems to make no difference.So help me,please.
[image]

Comment: Is that orange color table view's background color? How is it drawn?

Comment: @PradeepK It's a single UIView

Comment: Try setting the selectedBackgroundView property of the tableviewcell to a orange view

Comment: @PradeepK Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: @PradeepK I tried but no luck,thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `UITableViewCell` is selected, the OS goes through the view hierarchy and changes the `backgroundColor` of all of the subviews to `.clearColor()` so that it can properly display the background view.

You can create a custom `UIView` that resists this change. Something like this:

```
class NeverClearView: UIView {

    override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return super.backgroundColor
        }
        set {
            if newValue != .clearColor() {
                super.backgroundColor = newValue
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's a perfect solution,and you told me why.Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `accessibilityLabel` to work around.
1.First set the orange view's `backgroundcolor` and `tintcolor` to be the same color that you wanted ,just as you have already done.

2.Enable the orange view's `accessibility`,and set it's `accessibilityLabel` property.
[image]

3.In your tableView's delegate,add this method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    for var view in  cell.contentView.subviews{
        if view.accessibilityLabel == "colorView"{
           view.backgroundColor = view.tintColor;
        }
    }
}
```

4.it will work like this: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks,it works but not an elegant solution.Thanks for your suggestion again!